# Does there exist the following theorem for complex case?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

‎Consider the following theorem (see theorem 7.17 of [W. Rudin. Priniciples of Mathematical Analysis, Mcgraw-Hilly, 1976.])‎

**Theorem.** Suppose ‎$‎\{f_n\}‎$ ‎is ‎sequence ‎of ‎functions, ‎differentiable ‎on ‎‎$‎[a,b]‎$ ‎and ‎such ‎that‎ $‎\{f_n(x_0)\}‎$ converges for some point ‎$x_0‎$‎ ‎on ‎‎$‎[a,b]‎$. If ‎$‎\{f'‎_n\}‎$ converges uniformly‎ ‎on ‎‎$‎[a,b]‎$, then ‎$‎\{f_n\}‎$ converges uniformly‎ ‎on ‎‎$‎[a,b]‎$ to a function ‎$‎f‎$ ‎and‎‎

‎\begin{align*}
f'‎(x)=‎\lim‎_{n\to\infty}‎‎f'‎_n(x),\;\;a\leq x \leq b.
\end{align*}

‎>‎I ‎know ‎that ‎the ‎Theorem is stated for ‎real ‎case‎, but in my research I dealt to complex case and ‎‎Now my question is :‎‎

Does there exist the above (or similar) theorem for complex case? (i.e., Suppose ‎$‎\{f_n\}‎$ ‎is ‎sequence ‎of complex ‎functions, ‎differentiable ‎on an open domain ‎$‎D‎$‎ ‎and ‎such ‎that‎ $‎\{f_n(z_0)\}‎$ converges for some point ‎$z_0‎$‎ ‎on an open domain ‎$‎D‎‎$. If ‎$‎\{f'‎_n\}‎$ converges uniformly‎ ‎on ‎‎an open domain ‎$‎D‎$, then ‎$‎\{f_n\}‎$ converges uniformly‎ ‎on an open domain ‎$‎D‎$ to a function ‎$‎f‎$ ‎and‎‎
‎‎‎$f'‎(z)=‎\lim‎_{n\to\infty}‎‎f'‎_n(z),\;\;z\in ‎D‎‎.‎‎$‎‎‎)?  If yes, what is refrences. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.
‎

Comment: How do you write the derivative? It should be $\;f'_n\;$ ...

Comment: Even the result for the real case does not hold if $[a,b]$ is replaced by an open set. For example if $f_n(x)=\frac  x n$ then $f_n'$ converges  uniformly $\mathbb R$ to $0$ but $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Most of the theorems can be used in two cases (real and complex) with some changes. I hope that it happens for this theorem.

Comment: Somehow related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567637/when-does-the-normality-of-the-family-of-derivatives-imply-that-the-family-itsel

Answer (score 2):

Here is one version of the theorem for the complex case

Let $D$ be a convex open set and $f_n,f$ be holomorphic functions on $D$. If $f_n'$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D$ and $f_n(z_0) \to f(z_0)$ for some $z_0$ then there is a holomorphic function $h$ such that $f_n \to h$ uniformly on compact subsets and $\lim f_n'(z)=h'(z)$.

Proof: $f_n(z)=f_n(z_0)+\int_{[z_0,z]}f_n'(w)dw$ where $[z_0,z]$ denotes the line segment from $z_0$ to $z$. if $g$ is the limit of $f_n'$ the we see that $f_n$ converges  uniformly on compact stes to a funtion $h$ such that $h(z)=f(z_0)+\int_{[z_0,z]}g'(w)dw$. This implies that $h'=g$.

Comment: Would you tell me: Does your answer have any refrence?

Comment: See Stein and Shakarchi’s book on complex analysis, I believe Chapter 2, Section 5.