# Question Regarding Proof of Arzela Ascoli.

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, arzela-ascoli

I have just proved the following:

[image]

However my teacher provided me with the following:

[image]

Note that  $\Omega$ is open connected subset of $C$.

This is what i don't get. I know that on each compact subset of $\Omega$ there would exist a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges uniformly. But how do I know that this same subsequence converges(need not be uniformly) over $\Omega$ ?

How do I find a subsequence that converges over $\Omega$ and uniformly on compact subsets.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825491/42969: Choose an exhaustion by compact sets and apply a diagonal argument.

Comment: but $\Omega$ is not compact

Comment: But it is an increasing  union of compact sets, you'll find a construction in the referenced answer.